# Non-renewing copy of Microsoft Office?

Tags: microsoft-office

During a recent robbery, our churches computer was stolen.  Fortunately, we are insured and had off site back-ups. The insurance company will cover the cost of a new computer including software. What it does not cover is the cost of an annual subscription for Office 365. Is there a way to get Office in a way that doesn't require a yearly cost to the church?

Comment: if the church previously had office 365 as a subscription it still does. Login and deactivate the stolen computers subscription and then reinstall.

Comment: Sure;  Except it will be several times more expensive if you do it that way.  If it happens again it also means those licenses cannot be deactivated and thus basically lost.

Comment: People have to re-install OSes for various reasons, hardware dies, etc. You can call it in, will take hold time, but this kind of stuff happens all the time and Microsoft understands.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft still sells [Office 2013](http://products.office.com/en-us/home-and-business), which is a traditional desktop office suite, not a subscription to anything.